# What is the right way to let user retrieve client secret in OAuth 2?

Tags: password-policy, oauth, oauth2

In the OAuth website [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/) it says "*Most services provide a way for developers to retrieve the secret of an existing application, although some will only display the secret one time and require the developer store it themselves immediately*"

Earlier in the same text it says we should not store the secret in plaintext as it is equivalent to a password. How can I show the developer their client secret if I don't store it in plain text? I saw a lot of cases where the user can see their secret whenever they want instead of it being shown only once. What is the right way to do this?

If I have to store it in plaintext to be able to show it to the developer, then what are some additional security measures I can take?